# QucikBlox : How to delete user from application?

Tags: ios, quickblox

Can I delete quick blox user account within the application ? (Not from room )

I want that user can delete their account from application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, but only your own account because your are not an owner of others users accounts

```
 [QBUsers deleteUserWithID:48456 delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes You can Delete users in Quick Blox Using Application Credentials.
On the behalf of application you can delete users, but make sure you have users credentials.**

1. Authorize Application using app credentials
2. Login With User Credentilas Check If User
   exists Then you you can Delete user by quick blox user id or
   external user id.
3. Make sure don't change User GetToken With Application GetToken

   *If any issue please let me know.*

Comment: Is there a admin user that could delete any user? Where would those credentials be located?

Comment: admin who is created app in quick blox